# Is there any way to hide or remove the backup files in Xfce desktop

Tags: xfce

In my Xubuntu 12.04 I already updated to XFCE 4.10, but when I put text files on the desktop there is always backup files created.

Even though I use the shortcut link of that text file on my desktop, still the same result. I mean for each of the text file I edit there is always the backup files with them. Is there any solution? Or do I have to access the files from some folder?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `.hidden` in the desktop. Open it with a text editor and add the names of files you want to hide.

If there are numerous files you want to hide, open the terminal, change cd to desktop, and run the following command to hide all files ending with ~  :

```
for i in *~; do echo "$i"; done > .hidden
```

Note: I don't have an XFCE system so i haven't tested it out.