# Why does the ls command show deleted files?

Tags: command-line, ls

When I type `ls` in the terminal, it shows the files that are present as well as the files that I have deleted. How can I see the *current files only*, and why does `ls` keep a record of deleted files?

`ls` shows the deleted file names followed by a tilde (`~`).

Comment: Does it shows any tild(~) symbol at the end of deleted files @Vasu

Comment: Please include the output of `ls` verbatim in your question (formatted as code).

Comment: @Ravan Yes it shows tilt symbol at the end of deleted files

Comment: they are mostly back-up files created by text editors. You can view them and If you are sure you don't want them,  you can delete them as well.

Comment: @Ron How to delete them and why do i want them? What is their use?

Comment: @Ron using `rm` command i have to delete them one by one? But i have such 50 files? Suggest some other way?

Comment: Have you tried commands in my answer @Vasu,..anyone useful...

Comment: @VasuDevGarg if you find any of the posts below useful, do not forget to mark it as the answer to your question :)

Comment: @Ron Why the tilt files are not shown in GUI?

Comment: @Ron That's not working!!!

Comment: of course, it will. :) see http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg10t7.htm for more

Comment: @Ron Yes it worked!! The problem was that i was trying Clt-H in Desktop which is not working but in home it is. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
printf '%s\n' *

echo *

ls -U
```

any one of those instead of `ls` reference [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222492/what-is-the-alternative-for-ls-command-in-linux)

The `~` symbol may runtime *cache* or *backup files*.For that refer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1892139)

I edited this after seeing your comment;use this command to delete those backup files (files with `~` symbol)

```
find ./ -name '*~' | xargs rm
```

Comment: Just know I edited @Ron....OP asking to see only current files..

Comment: better now.  `find` has a `-delete` option as well. So `find ./ -name '*~' -delete` will work as well.

Comment: @Ron the edit was helpful!!

Comment: Is there an alternative such that the tilt(~) files that are created by the editors are not shown which are shown in `ls` command so that i have not to delete them?

Comment: @Ravan I found that I could hide tilt files by making an alias for ls and putting it into .bashrc ..... code to put in .bashrc is `alias ls="ls --ignore-backups $@"` but it is not working?

Comment: @Vasu do you want to delete those tilt files or hide.....

Comment: @Ravan I firstly want to delete them..... but now I want to modify my ls command so that it doesn't show those files

Comment: @VasuDevGarg just use `ls` without  `-a` and you won't see hidden files.

Comment: @Vasu refer [http://askubuntu.com/questions/261860](http://askubuntu.com/questions/261860/is-there-any-way-to-hide-or-remove-the-backup-files-in-xfce-desktop)

Comment: @Wildcard sorry to reject your edit--but I purposely used `ls -U` but you changed to `ls -a`--.sorry

Answer (score 9):

`ls` does **not** cache file names. It really does show you exactly what is currently on the file system. However, as [@Ravan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664823/why-ls-command-shows-the-deleted-files#comment959297_664823) hinted, there may be similarly named files in your directory. These are typically runtime caches or lock files created by programs such as Vim and Emacs, but could be pretty much anything. For example, if I do the following in one terminal:

```
$ touch foo
$ vim foo
```

Then I'll see the following in another terminal:

```
$ ls -A
foo  .foo.swp
```

`.foo.swp` is a hidden temporary file which will be deleted if Vim exits nicely.

Such files can be safely deleted if they are left around from earlier editing sessions which are no longer open. Just make sure you [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) the file names, since they may contain special characters like tilde (`~`):

```
$ rm '.foo~'
```

Comment: how to delete them ?

Answer (score 1):

The name followed by "~" is actually a cache file.
When you delete the file it may still remain as an hidden file for the nautilus but the "ls" command will show them.

Run `rm *~` to remove those files.